# Does convexity of $e^x$ imply boundedness of this integral?

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Does a Borel measurable function $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which fulfils

$\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 e^x < \infty$

imply that

$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx < \infty?$

I have tried to apply Jensen's inequality, but have not gotten to a conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$\Large 
f(x)=\begin{cases} x^{-\frac14} &\text{if }\,0 < x \leq 1,\\\\
         \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{x}&\text{if }\,    x > 1, 
\end{cases}
$$

then we have

$$\Large 
f(x)^2e^{x}=\begin{cases} x^{-\frac12}e^{x} &\text{if }\,0 < x \leq 1,\\\\
         \frac{1}{x^2}&\text{if }\,    x > 1 
\end{cases}
$$

which is integrable over $(0, \infty)$, but

$$\Large 
f(f(x))=\begin{cases} x^{\frac14}e^{-\frac{x^{-\frac14}}{2}} &\text{if }\,0 < x \leq 1,\\\\
         x^{\frac14}e^\frac{x}{8}&\text{if }\,    x > 1 
\end{cases}
$$

is not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I made a typo in my question that I somehow didn't see before posting. It is supposed to be $\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|dx$ in the last expression.

Comment: @Manbearpig Well in that case this is a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz with $f(x) = e^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cdot f(x)e^{\frac{x}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought maybe Jensen's inequality was a more obvious choice?

Comment: @Manbearpig That depends on who you're asking, if you want to prove it using Jensen you need a probability measure, i.e. in this case you will have to introduce a probability density function of some sort. For example if we use the fact that $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x= 1$ then Jensen gives us $\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)| \mathrm{d}x\right)^2 = \left(\int_{0}^{\infty} |f(x)|e^{x} e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\right)^2 \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(f(x)e^{x}\right)^2 e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)^2e^{x} \mathrm{d}x < \infty$.